# Projecting rasters in r terra package

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, terra

I would like to project a raster using a shapefile read in via the "vect" command. I have made the following work:

```
r <- rast(xmin=-110, xmax=-90, ymin=40, ymax=60, ncols=40, nrows=40)
r3<-terra::project(r,crs(west))
```

(where "west" is a shapefile read in with vect)

But what I want to verify is that the crs command used to extract the coordinate reference system from the shapefile is passing on the WKT format? In other words, given the changes to GDAL, **if this ref system happened to be in a datum other than WGS84**, would this be an appropriate way to pass on the shape's coordinate reference system to the project command? And similarly, passing on the PROJ4 string would NOT be the correct method...

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
 crs(west)
```

you see what it passes on (a `WKT2` description of the CRS).
For readability you can do

```
 cat(crs(west), "\n")
```

And for the proj-string notation.

```
 crs(west, proj=TRUE)
```

Whether using a PROJ-string would be correct depends on the CRS. It generally works fine, but not if you are using a old or local datum. But you do not show the CRS of `west` so I cannot know what might apply here.

Comment: Sorry I'll rephrase: I'm trying to determine whether the following statement is true: 
 "when working with an older or local datum, using crs() without the proj=TRUE argument is the proper way to pass on the coordinate reference info to the terra:project command"

Comment: I think I answered that question. `proj=T` is for human consumption.